# Printing of extra spaces in minicom

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

When I try to print some function name in minicom for `linux-3.10` kernel and x86 board, I get extra spaces in each lineof minicom. I have switched on the Line Wrap in minicom but same problem exists. This does not happen with `ARM` board. It gets printed correctly in ARM board.

```
x86_64_start_kernel()
            reset_early_page_tables()
```

The code is for printing each name on the border. Is there any setting to be done in minicom?

Comment: You should probably configure `minicom` to add CR (`\r`) character after each LF (`\n`). See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283924/can-minicom-translate-incoming-newline-n-to-crlf) for details.

Comment: Wow it worked thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In minicom press `Ctrl+A Z`. This will show the menu. Then press `U` ("Add Carriage Ret"), and minicom will add the `CR` symbol to each `LF` symbol automatically.

**PERMANENT SOLUTION**

You can execute `minicom -s` as root, choose `Screen and keyboard`, then press `T - Add carriage return`, and `Save setup as dfl` to turn this option ON systemwide. Or you can save this configuration in a separate Config-file, and then use as `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 /etc/minicom/minirc.myconfig`.